# Changing a Unix Timestamp to a Date in google sheet each time data is added

Tags: google-sheets, unix, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a unix time stamp to a date in Google sheet. The problem I am having is I need the unix stamp to change to a date each time using a formula every time the data gets added to the sheet. the formula i am using is =S2/1000/60/60/24 + DATE(1970,1,1).

How can is create a formula that will convert the unix stamp each time the data is added to that column without doing it manually? Hopefully I've provided enough information

Answer (score 0):

try in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(S2:S="",,S2:S/1000/60/60/24 + DATE(1970,1,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [EPOCHTODATE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13193461)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(S2:S),EPOCHTODATE(S2:S),))
```

- 

[image]